# Parse search query with Lucene and build Hibernate criteria based on that

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

The requirement is to build a simplified searching functionality over a limited number of fields that are kept in a separate single table. Using Solr or like is not an option at the moment, everything has to work within one webapp. The database is MSSQL. What I am trying to do is to utilize Lucene query parser and build Hibernate criteria from that. Despite my initial impression that it wouldn't be too hard, I can't figure out how to build criteria for a complex query.

Here is a quick test I created to parse the query string with Lucene (4.7.2)

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);
QueryParser luceneParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_47, "", analyzer);
String queryString = "(name:\"Luke Skywalker\" AND father:unknown OR fname:Luke) or (name:yoda)";
Query luceneQuery = luceneParser.parse(queryString);
```

....

```
public class QueryInterpreter {
    public void parse(Query query) {
        if (query instanceof TermQuery) {
            termQuery((TermQuery) query);
        } else if (query instanceof BooleanQuery) {
            booleanQuery((BooleanQuery) query);
        } else if (query instanceof PhraseQuery) {
            phraseQuery((PhraseQuery) query);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
        }
    }
    public void booleanQuery(BooleanQuery query) {
        for (BooleanClause clause : query.getClauses()) {
            parse(clause.getQuery());
        }
    }
    public void phraseQuery(PhraseQuery query) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Term term : query.getTerms()) {
            sb.append(term.text());
            sb.append(" ");
        }

    }
    public void termQuery(TermQuery query) {
        Term term = query.getTerm();
    }
}
```

Lucene first thing coverts the search string into `(+name:\"Luke Skywalker\" +father:unknown fname:Luke) name:yoda`. Basically then it iterates through terms with isRequired() set for each of them. Hibernate works differently - you create a criteria object and keep adding Criterions with pairs of values. And I cannot figure out the way how to convert one to another. What I think I need is a generic purpose Junction object to attach Criterions to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out, will share my solution here in case someone will be facing the same problem.

The first step in the right direction was to realise that `QueryParser` doesn't deal with boolean logic well. For example `(+name:\"Luke Skywalker\" +father:unknown fname:Luke) name:yoda` is a different search from `(name:\"Luke Skywalker\" AND father:unknown OR fname:Luke) or (name:yoda)`. Don't know why QueryParser even accepts boolean logic, it's just plain confusing.

The solution is to use `PrecedenceQueryParser`.

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);
PrecedenceQueryParser luceneParser = new PrecedenceQueryParser(analyzer);
luceneParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query luceneQuery = luceneParser.parse(searchQuery, "name");
```

And then create a Hibernate Criterion from that. Obviously you can't support full range of Lucene search capabilities in a relational database, but that's never been a requirement.

```
public Criterion buildHibernateQuery(Query luceneQuery) {
    return parse(luceneQuery);
}

private Criterion parse(Query query) {
    if (query instanceof TermQuery) {
        return parse((TermQuery) query);
    } else if (query instanceof BooleanQuery) {
        return parse((BooleanQuery) query);
    } else if (query instanceof PhraseQuery) {
        return parse((PhraseQuery) query);
    } else if (query instanceof PrefixQuery) {
        return parse((PrefixQuery) query);
    } else if (query instanceof WildcardQuery) {
        return parse((WildcardQuery) query);
    } else {
        LOG.error(String.format("%s unsupported", query.getClass()));
    }
}

private Criterion parse(TermQuery query) {
    Term term = query.getTerm();
    return createNameValueRestriction(term.field(), term.text());
}

private Criterion parse(BooleanQuery query) {
    if (query.getClauses().length == 1) {
        return parse(query.getClauses()[0].getQuery());
    }
    Junction junction = createJunction(query.getClauses()[0]);

    for (BooleanClause clause: query.getClauses()) {
        junction.add(parse(clause.getQuery()));
    }
    return junction;
}

private Junction createJunction(BooleanClause booleanClause) {
    if (booleanClause.isRequired()) {
        return Restrictions.conjunction();
    } else {
        return Restrictions.disjunction();
    }
}

private Criterion parse(PhraseQuery query) {
    String field = query.getTerms()[0].field();
    StringBuilder phraseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Term term : query.getTerms()) {
        phraseBuilder.append(term.text());
        phraseBuilder.append(" ");
    }

    return createNameValueRestriction(field, phraseBuilder.toString().trim());
}

private Criterion createNameValueRestriction(String field, String value) {
    return Restrictions.and(
            Restrictions.eq("jsonPath", field),
            Restrictions.eq("answer", value)
            );
}

private Criterion parse(PrefixQuery query) {
    Term term = query.getPrefix();
    return parseLikeQuery(term.field(), term.text(), MatchMode.START);
}

private Criterion parse(WildcardQuery query) {
    Term term = query.getTerm();
    String wildCardEscaped = Pattern.quote(String.valueOf(WildcardQuery.WILDCARD_STRING));
    String termText = term.text().replaceAll(wildCardEscaped, "");
    return parseLikeQuery(term.field(), termText, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
}


private Criterion parseLikeQuery(String field, String value, MatchMode matchMode) {
    return Restrictions.and(
            Restrictions.eq("jsonPath", field),
            Restrictions.like("answer", value, matchMode)
            );
}
```

Hope someone will find this useful.